# How can I reference to same Rule being called more than once in ANTLR?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar which is similar to the one below

```
E returns [String vals] : 
    E '+' E {$vals = $E.vals+$E.vals}|
    E '-' E {$vals = $E.vals+$E.vals}
```

I want to access two different 'E' values, but I am unable to do so.
I want to differentiate between 3 'E' rules, one which is the base and other 2 which are being called.

I am creating a grammar which I will be using to evaluate certain expressions.

The operators '+' and '-' are some arbitraty operators.

Comment: How similar is that snippet really to your actual grammar? It has a lot of problems that are unrelated to your question (`E` is a lexer rule, which makes no sense; your actions are expressions, when they should be statements; there are no declared return values; `+` and `-` have different precedence; there is no `-` operator for strings and the `+` operator won't do what you want).

Comment: @sepp2k My actual grammar is very different from this, actually for the sake of simplicity I abstracted my grammar so that my actual requirement gets highlighted. Return type, precedence among other things are being being handled by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to multiple uses of the same rule in actions, you can add labels to them like this:

```
e1=exp op=('+'|'-') e2=exp {
  // code that uses $e1 and $e2
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that’s exactly what I needed.